# How to get Wifi provider information in ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am developing an IOS app where i need to access wifi information. I have enabled "Access Wifi information" capability and from that i am getting SSID, BSSID and SSIDATA. in SSIS i am getting name of my router. But not getting network provider name. i have checked with other app and they are also providing wifi provider name like "BSNL". I have also tried using CoreTelephony. but it is only providing my sim network providers like jio and Airtel, but not wifi provider.

Comment: What do you call a Wifi provider ?

Comment: You would need to send some data to a server you run, so that the server can determine your external IP address (which may or may not be your device IP address because of NAT). You then need to reference this  address against a database of service provider IP ranges to identify the (probable) service provider.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the details from Apple on Wifi SSID access:

Starting with iOS 13, the CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo API will no longer return valid Wi-Fi SSID and BSSID information. Instead, the information returned by default will be:

SSID: “Wi-Fi” or “WLAN” (“WLAN" will be returned for the China SKU)

BSSID: "00:00:00:00:00:00"

If your app is using this API, we encourage you to adopt alternative approaches that don’t require Wi-Fi or network information. Valid SSID and BSSID information from CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo will still be provided to VPN apps, apps that have used NEHotspotConfiguration to configure the current Wi-Fi network, and apps that have obtained permission to access user location through Location Services.

Test your app on the latest iOS 13 beta to make sure it works properly. If your app requires valid Wi-Fi SSID and BSSID information to function, you can do the following:

- For accessory setup apps, use the NEHotSpotConfiguration API, which now has the option to pass a prefix of the SSID hotspot your app expects to connect to.
- For other types of apps, use the CoreLocation API to request the user’s consent to access location information.

Learn more by reading the [updated documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/1614126-cncopycurrentnetworkinfo) or viewing the the [Advances in Networking](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/712/) session video from WWDC19. You can also submit a TSI for code-level support.